# Append String To Int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to add a `%` sign to a calculation I'm doing in MS SQL Server.  This is the syntax I am using

```
Cast(Round(Coalesce(totalsaleamt,0) * 100,0) As Int) + '%'
```

but I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int

What is the proper way to make this concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like:

```
Convert(Varchar(100),Cast(Round(Coalesce(totalsaleamt,0) * 100,0) As Int)) + '%'
```

That will convert your INT into a varchar and it will then be possible to add the % sign.

Comment: Trying this syntax I get an error of ``Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'``

Comment: oups... my bad (typo). I changed my answer

Comment: Perfect, thank you